# SARIMA estimation

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation, partial-correlation

I am trying to manually estimate the non-seasonal components of an SARIMA (p,d,q)x(P,D,Q)[s]. I thought the estimation is going the same way like in ARIMA, but the output says somehow something different.

I have an autocorrelation in the acf correlogram and one significance bound at lag 1 in the pacf. That means I have an autocorrelation first order.

I'm confused now, why `auto.arima` is giving me the result (0,1,1)x(0,0,1)[12] instead of (1,1,0)x(0,0,1)[12]

Here is my code example:

```
timeseries <- ts(daten, start=c(1955,1), freq=12)

> timeseries
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
1955  1.8  1.7  1.5  1.2  1.5  1.5  1.6  1.8  1.5  1.5  1.6  1.3
1956  0.7  0.6  0.4  0.9  0.9  0.8  0.8  0.6  0.6  0.4  0.4  0.2
1957  0.2  0.1  0.6  0.8  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0  1.3
1958  1.7  1.7  1.4  1.0  0.9  1.3  1.3  1.0  1.5  1.4  1.4  2.2
1959  1.3  1.7  1.7  2.2  2.8  2.5  2.2  2.3  1.8  1.6  1.3  1.4
1960  2.2  1.8  1.9  1.6  1.1  0.8  1.1  1.1  1.1  1.4  1.2  1.2
1961  0.9  1.2  1.3  0.9  0.7  0.8  0.8  1.2  1.0  1.0  1.4  1.0
1962  1.1  0.8  1.1  1.7  2.1  2.0  2.1  2.1  2.0  2.3  2.0  2.3
1963  1.6  1.9  1.6  1.4  1.6  1.8  1.8  1.9  2.5  2.3  2.2  2.1
1964  2.1  2.1  1.9  2.3  2.1  2.0  2.1  1.8  1.0  1.1  1.5  1.4
1965  1.8  1.9  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.7  2.7  3.3  3.1
1966  2.9  3.0  3.3  2.6  3.1  3.4  3.5  3.3  3.0  2.5  1.4  1.1
1967  0.9  1.0  0.4  0.8  0.0  0.0 -0.7 -0.1 -0.5 -0.1  0.3  0.8
1968  0.8  0.5  1.2  1.0  1.2  0.8  1.2  1.0  1.3  1.3  1.6  1.9
1969  2.0  2.2  2.3  2.7  2.4  2.4  2.6  2.5  2.9  2.9  2.8  2.3
1970  2.3  2.5  2.3  2.2  2.2  2.0  1.9  2.2  2.1  2.1  1.9  2.0
1971  1.9  1.8  1.8  1.1  1.6  1.9  1.9   NA 

diffts <- diff(timeseries,12)
tsdisplay(diffts, lag.max=36)
```

[image]

But `auto.arima` is giving me the following output:

```
auto.arima(timeseries)

Series: timeseries 
ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[12]                    

Coefficients:
          ma1     sma1
      -0.1280  -0.7260
s.e.   0.0684   0.0584

sigma^2 estimated as 0.07113:  log likelihood=-23.77
AIC=53.54   AICc=53.66   BIC=63.42
```

Comment: Why don't you post the data ?

Comment: sorry i missed that, thought it wasnt needed. the data is now posted

Comment: Please post the original series in single column format or send it to me at my email contact

Comment: Your ACF/PACF plots are of the seasonally differenced series, so what makes you think an ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,0,1)[12] is appropriate?

Comment: I was thinking that i have to difference the time series twelve times and with the results out of the correlogram i get the parameters for my seasonal arima model.
Due the autocorrelation i thought the non-seasonal parameters are (1,1,0). 
(0,0,1) due that the seasonal lag spikes at 12,24,36 are falling the pacf is 0. Furthermore we have a identical lag spike at lag 12 in with acf correlogram, so the acf seasonal is 1.

Answer (score 3):

Your acf of the seasonally differenced series strongly suggests the need for a regular difference. What follows is the acf of the doubly differenced series ( your series reularly differenced) [image] . THis acf suggests an autoregressive seasonal factor as the partial acf of lag 12 and 24 are apparently significant although since the seasonal coefficient will be between -.4 and +.4 it reall won't matter if you call it a seasnal ma of lag12. When models are tried including an ma(1) statistical significance for the ma(1) is rejected and is thusly not included. A good final model should include some indicators for anonmalous data .[image] , So in conlusion your preferred model is in your terms (0,1,0)(1,1,0) OR (0,1,0)(0,1,1).

Comment: How did u make that output? i haven't seen a similiar output so far, and what did u mean with "regular difference"?

Comment: @bastian I used AUTOBOX (http://www.autobox.com) to do the analysis. If you wish you can cintact me at my email address so I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

In oreder to get correct results from auto.arima() command try using it as shown below:
auto.arima(timeseries,stepwise = F, approximation = FALSE)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is unlinkely, that this answer will help the original poster, who asked 3 years ago. Nevertheless, it may help somebody else in the future.